# Can any function be used as a hook?

Tags: hooks

I'm looking to override [format_size()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_size/7), but I'm not sure if this is possible in a module.
If I implement `myModule_format_size()` or in a theme `myTheme_format_size()` will the hook be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Not all functions invokes a hook in other modules. As we can see in http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_size/7 there is no [module_invoke_all](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7) is called.

Here is how we define [module_invoke_all](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7)

> Invokes a hook in all enabled modules that implement it.

```
function module_invoke_all($hook) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  // Remove $hook from the arguments.
  unset($args[0]);
  $return = array();
  foreach (module_implements($hook) as $module) {
    $function = $module . '_' . $hook;
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      $result = call_user_func_array($function, $args);
      if (isset($result) && is_array($result)) {
        $return = array_merge_recursive($return, $result);
      }
      elseif (isset($result)) {
        $return[] = $result;
      }
    }
  }

  return $return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So in theory, there is no way to edit the function above without "hacking core"??

Comment: Yes right now there is no way to extend that function. http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal, a hook is not a function that is called instead of a function defined from Drupal; it is a function that Drupal, or any third-party module, calls through [module_invoke_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7), or [module_invoke()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7).
In your case, `mymodule_format_size()` will never called instead of `format_size()`, but it will be eventually called as `hook_format_size()` implementation (whatever purpose it has), if a module invokes that hook.

Since it is not possible to expand `format_size()`, which doesn't invoke any hook, contrary to [format_username()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_username/7), the only way to change the code executed from `format_size()` is to act on the functions calling it. In other words:

- If `format_size()` is used in a form submission handler, then you could alter that form to remove that form submission handler, and replace it with your own handler, which doesn't call `format_size()`
- If `format_size()` is used from a template file that is used from a theme function implemented in a module, you could override the template file in a theme
- If `format_size()` is used from a theme function, you could override the theme function (in a module or in a theme) with a version of the theme function that doesn't call `format_size()`